# Angular 2 Error Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to call post api on button click but I shows this error:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Code:

```
changeStatus(id) {
    this.http.post('https://localhost:44300/api/apis/ChangeStatus/' + id)
        .subscribe(
            data => this._data = data.json(),
            err => this.logError(err)
        );
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: second line code `this.http.post('https://localhost:44300/api/apis/ChangeStatus/' + id)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`http.post` expects a body to be sent to the target host.

```ts
http.post(url, body, requestOptions)
```

So if you just want an empty body, because you have no additional data to send, you could do this:

```ts
changeStatus(id) {
    // mind the empty string here as a second parameter
    this.http.post('https://localhost:44300/api/apis/ChangeStatus/' + id, "") 
        .subscribe(
            data => this._data = data.json(),
            err => this.logError(err)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`post` method requires at least two parameters, first 'URL', and second 'Body' and in your code you are just passing URL not body.